# Selenium Python: move_to_element doesn't move

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am currently working on a Script that completes the game [little alchemy 2](https://littlealchemy2.com/) automatically.

As the game progresses the library of the already discovered Items grows and eventually you have to scroll to get to some of the lower ones. 
Selenium throws the exception `MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException` when the Item I try to grab is not on the screen.

I tried fixing this by catching the exception and then using `move_to_element` to bring the Item in reach of Selenium. But when I tried it out nothing happened. Any Ideas?

```
try:
            ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(elempic2, workspace).perform()
        except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
            print ("Need to Scroll because if element 2")
            ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(elempic2).perform()
            ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(elempic2, workspace).perform()
        print ("Element 2 dragged: " + str(elemname2.text))
```

**Error that gets thrown**:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "littlealch.py", line 60, in findelements
    ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(elempic2, workspace).perform()
  File "/home/joco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/action_chains.py", line 80, in perform
    self.w3c_actions.perform()
  File "/home/joco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/actions/action_builder.py", line 76, in perform
    self.driver.execute(Command.W3C_ACTIONS, enc)
  File "/home/joco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/joco/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException: Message: (1624, 957.5) is out of bounds of viewport width (1920) and height (942)
```

If you want to try it out yourself [here](https://github.com/Jocomol/Zauberlehring) is the repo.

Thank you for your Help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would convert the scrolling logic to something that doesn't require the target element to be in view, like something along these lines:

```
y_position = 0
searching = True

while searching:
  try:
    ActionChains(driver).drag_and_drop(elempic2, workspace).perform()
    searching = False
  except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
    y_position += 500
    driver.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(y_position) + ');')
  print ('Element 2 dragged: ' + str(elemname2.text))
```

This just uses JavaScript to scroll down the page until the work can be performed.