# Two methods to download current day filters trough selenium firefox webdriver: scroll down the page and filters

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

I want to download the currently day files from a folder in sharepoint.

TL;DR: I've tried two ways (scroll down and apply filters) but none worked.

Since sharepoint loads data in batches of 30 files, first I've tried to [scroll down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41744368/scrolling-to-element-using-webdriver) the page in order to load the next batch, but with the [firefox bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44777053/selenium-movetargetoutofboundsexception-with-firefox) and me trying to scroll down [part of the web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63901621/selenium-google-chrome-scrolling), it was impossible.

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath('some_path')
actions = ActionChains(browser)
actions.move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Even I tried to move it [little by little](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54292414/selenium-python-move-to-element-doesnt-move) for each file not in the screen, but didn't work.

```
except MoveTargetOutOfBoundsException:
    y_position += 500
    browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, ' + str(y_position) + ');')
```

So, my next plan was to apply filters (there are buttons, it seems an ez way to do it, right? No...). There are two ways you can set up a date: slider bar and checkbox.

1. **Slider bar**

By default appears full and I want to empty it.

This is the default state.

```
<div id="Slider654" class="ms-Slider-slideBox ms-Slider-showTransitions slideBox-213" aria-disabled="false" role="slider" tabindex="0" data-is-focusable="true" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuetext="Modificado desde 2023" aria-label="Modificado desde 2023. Use las teclas de flecha para filtrar por fecha, desde 2023 a Hoy">
<div class="ms-Slider-line line-215">
    *<span class="ms-Slider-thumb thumb-214" style="left: 0%;"></span>
    <span class="lineContainer-216 ms-Slider-inactive inactiveSection-218" style="width: 0%;"></span>
    *<span class="lineContainer-216 ms-Slider-active activeSection-217" style="width: 0%;"></span>
    *<span class="lineContainer-216 ms-Slider-inactive inactiveSection-218" style="width: 100%;"></span>
</div></div>
```

And I want to change to this state.

```
<div id="Slider654" class="ms-Slider-slideBox ms-Slider-showTransitions slideBox-213" aria-disabled="false" role="slider" tabindex="0" data-is-focusable="true" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="5" aria-valuenow="5" aria-valuetext="Modificado hoy" aria-label="Modificado hoy. Use las teclas de flecha para filtrar por fecha, desde 2023 a Hoy">
<div class="ms-Slider-line line-215">
    *<span class="ms-Slider-thumb thumb-214" style="left: 100%;"></span>
    <span class="lineContainer-216 ms-Slider-inactive inactiveSection-218" style="width: 0%;"></span>
    *<span class="lineContainer-216 ms-Slider-active activeSection-217" style="width: 100%;"></span>
    *<span class="lineContainer-216 ms-Slider-inactive inactiveSection-218" style="width: 0%;"></span>
</div></div>
```

The * remarks the lines changed plus the `aria-valuenow` var in the first div that changes the value from 0 to 5.

I've tried to change these values but even changing them, **it doesn't refresh the page.**

2. **Checkbox**

I have the script to check the correct box.

```
i = 1
exists = True
while exists:
    try:
        f_date_i = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[' + str(i) + ']/div/div[1]/label/span').text
        d = datetime.strptime(f_date_i, "%d/%m/%Y")
        if d == datetime_today:
            f_date_i = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[4]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[' + str(i) + ']')
            browser.execute_script("arguments[0].setAttribute('data-is-checked','true')", f_date_i)
            exists = False
        i += 1
    except NoSuchElementException:
        exists = False
```

But when I press 'Apply' button, page doesn't change.

### I think I'm missing something with the filters and I have to change something else...